# file-based NoSql database?

Tags: php, sqlite, nosql

I am interested in building a web app (**PHP5**) based on a NoSql database (with structs storage, like **MongoDB**).

But I am also a big fan of **SQLite** spirit and not having to bother about configuring a separate server.

Do you know of any file-based NoSQL database ?

Thanks in advance,
Raphael

Comment: +, I have always searched for something like this. Convenience of MongoDB compared with SQLite no-server-requiredness.

Comment: BTW, I was considering using SQLite and implementing some sort of RDF-like graphs upon it. 
But I don't want to reinvent the wheel, and MongoDB seems really powerful.

Answer (score 7):

you can use [unqlite](http://unqlite.org/) + [php-ext-unqlite](https://github.com/kjdev/php-ext-unqlite)

> UnQLite is a in-process software library which implements a self-contained, serverless, zero-configuration, transactional NoSQL database engine. UnQLite is a document store database similar to MongoDB, Redis, CouchDB etc. as well a standard Key/Value store similar to BerkeleyDB, LevelDB, etc.
>
> A complete database with multiple collections, is contained in a single disk file. The database file format is cross-platform, you can freely copy a database between 32-bit and 64-bit systems or between big-endian and little-endian architectures.

or use [MongoLite](https://github.com/aheinze/MongoLite)

> Schemaless database on top of SqLite

or use [SDB](http://pagenotes.com/wordpress/2011/12/08/sdb/)

Answer (score 3):

There are many key-value open-source databases that can be linked directly into your application. Here are a few:

- BerkeleyDB (now Oracle embedded database)
- Tokyo cabinet (hash table based)
- hamsterdb (disclaimer: i'm the author)

I'm not sure if BDB or TC offer PHP bindings. hamsterdb does not (yet).

Comment: I don't do much PHP, so I'm not 100% certain, but I'd be very surprised if BDB doesn't have bindings for PHP (and pretty much every other non-toy language out there), given its history.

Comment: Hamsterdb has such a cute logo :D  But it's licensed under the GPL so I guess it's only meant for hobbyists who don't know better.

Comment: If you think that only hobbyists write GPL code then I could give you many many examples which prove the opposite. hamsterdb is dual licensed and has license exceptions for BSD, Apache and many others. If you want to use it in a commercial project then you have to buy a license.